# prove $||A_n^{-1}||$ is bounded

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, matrices, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty{} \in GL_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) $.

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n = A$; $A\neq0$ is invertible.

I have a notion that for any norm $$||\cdot||:GL_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+\cup\{0\},$$

$||A_n^{-1}||$ is bounded. How can I show it formally?

Comment: Do you know how to do it for real numbers? (That is, the 1-dimensional case.)

Comment: Sure. and still cannot induce the required proof :)

Comment: But it is the same! :-) While you loose $|ab|= |a||b|$ you only need this with $\le$ which is true for some norms. And as all norms are equivalent you are good.

Comment: Sorry it take this back. Maybe I mixed up something mentally.

Comment: You are right but I can't figure why it is true for matrices.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the map $X \mapsto X^{-1}$ is a continuous map from $GL$ back to itself.  Moreover, the map $\|\cdot\| : M_{m \times n} \to \Bbb R$ is continuous.

It follows that the map $X \mapsto \|X^{-1}\|$ is a continuous map from $GL_{n \times n}$ to $\Bbb R$, since it is the composition of two continuous map.  So, since $(A_n)$ is a sequence in $GL$ with $A_n \to A$, $\|A_n^{-1}\|$ must be a sequence in $\Bbb R$ with $\|A_n^{-1}\| \to \|A^{-1}\|$.

Since $(\|A_n^{-1}\|)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is a convergent sequence, it is necessarily bounded.

Comment: While correct I'd worry this argument may be circular for the given context.

Comment: My guess is that the statement OP is looking at is a statement like "given a sequence of invertible matrices $A_n \to A$, $A$ is invertible if and only if $\|A_n^{-1}\|$ is bounded".  The question OP *didn't* ask about is a standard problem, while the "easier" direction might be skipped.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have mentioned... I try not to assume continuity of the given map - the way I build the proof makes this argument circular.

Comment: It's easy to prove the determinant is continuous in other ways.  For example, Cramer's rule gives a rational function that gives you the inverse, and rational functions are continuous in their domain.